# Show child of this parent click vue

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I want to show the immediate child after clicking on its parent. Its easy on jquery, hard on vue, how can I do it?

template:

```
<boxes inline-template>    
<div class="white-box" @click="toggleTick">Purchase only 
        <div v-if="showTick"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></div>
    </div>
</boxes>
```

js

```
Vue.component('boxes', {
    data: function () {
        return {
            showTick: false
        }
    },
    methods: {
        toggleTick () {
          this.showTick = !this.showTick
      } 
    }
})
  var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
        data: {

        }
  })
```

At the moment I have multiple "white-box" div, it shows the child div for all of them, I just want to show the div for the clicked parent's child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have behavior that you expect :

```js
Vue.component('boxes', {
    data: function () {
        return {
            showTick: false
        }
    }
})
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <boxes inline-template>    
    <div class="white-box" @click="showTick = !showTick">
      <span>
        Purchase only 
      </span>
      <div v-if="showTick">Component 1</div>
    </div>
  </boxes>
  <boxes inline-template>    
    <div class="white-box" @click="showTick = !showTick">
      <span>
        Purchase only 
      </span>
      <div v-if="showTick">Component 2</div>
    </div>
  </boxes>
</div>
```

Comment: this is great but how do I do it to only show the child div if it is not showing in any of the components? So only one child div can be showing at one time all of them

Comment: this did what I asked for, so thanks, but this link did what I really wanted, to only show one child at a time https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45521138/vue-js-to-add-class-active-when-click-and-remove-the-previous-one

Answer (score 1):

Your `white-boxes` are sharing the same `showTick` variable, so clicking on one fo them changes the value for all of them.

There are 2 available solutions to this:

- Have multiple `boxes` components and not multiple `white-boxes` under the same `boxes` component. Something take ends up looking like this in the DOM

  ```
  <boxes>...</boxes>
  <boxes>...</boxes>
  <boxes>...</boxes>
  ```
- Use an array for `showTick` and use an index when calling `toggleClick`. Also note that for the changes in the array to be reactive you need to use `Vue.set`.

I recommend the former solution.