# Function is defined but never used in the script section of a Vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3, vue-sfc

I am trying to manage my current website using Vue and more particularly Vue Router. As I am already using Bootstrap, I need some Javascript to manage the state of my buttons. The following code only works if I comment the `script` section.

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
          <header class="d-flex justify-content-center py-3 border-bottom">
              <ul class="nav nav-pills" id="navbar_nav">
                  <li class="nav-item"><router-link to="Add" type="button" class="nav-link" onclick="update_nav_bar(this);">Add</router-link></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><router-link to="Edit" type="button" class="nav-link" onclick="update_nav_bar(this);">Edit</router-link></li>
              </ul>
          </header>
  </div>
  <router-view/>
</template>

<script>
let navbar_nav = document.getElementById("navbar_nav");
function update_nav_bar(elem) {
    navbar_nav.getElementsByClassName("active")[0].classList.remove("active");
    elem.classList.add("active");
}
</script>
```

If I do not comment it, I get this error:

```
15:10  error  'update_nav_bar' is defined but never used
```

So far I removed a lot of `getElementById` calls in my code thanks to Vue. So I guess there is a more elegant (and working...) way to achieve what I want, but I am new to Vue and lack any hindsights. Could you help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define the function in the methods object. Or - if you use the composition-api - return the function from the `setup` fuction.

```js
<script>
let navbar_nav = document.getElementById("navbar_nav");

export default {
  methods: {
    update_nav_bar(elem) {
      navbar_nav.getElementsByClassName("active")[0].classList.remove("active");
      elem.classList.add("active");
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

But maybe you should rethink the function in general. Usually you can achieve this without manipulating the DOM manually with JavaScript.

Comment: I see, something like this, then : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45521138/vue-js-to-add-class-active-when-click-and-remove-the-previous-one/45522008 ?

Comment: Exactly, otherwise you always depend on your class names.